# iPad - best way to store data

Tags: ipad, data-storage

What is the best way to store big amount of data in your application on iPad? e.g. I want store lot of manuals in PDF (like 200-500MB) and use them?

Will be (these data) synced during synchronization in iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

You can store all applicationspecific stuff into your sandbox. Here is the path for NSDocumentDirectory. There are also other folders to store (eg. cache or libary)

```
NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [pathArray objectAtIndex:0]
```

When you do an iPad/Phone Backup your applicationdata will be backuped on the PC.

greets
Simon

Answer (score 1):

You should put them in the file system, and then use SQLite or CoreData to maintain the list of documents and their file names. If you put them in the app's Documents directory they will be included in the daily iTunes backups. If you put them in the cache folder (which one you'd have to check) they won't be backed up by iTunes.

Comment: You should remember to check this as the correct answer if it is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One good way would be www.dropbox.com and sign up for an account there (free for 5 gigs) and you can get the app for your phone...all you would have to do is download them from your cloud. I use it all the time. Cool thing is you have a folder on your computer called the dropbox folder and this folder will automatically sync all new files to the cloud. I suggest this method. I am not sure if iTunes does direct syncing for .pdf files. But I know you can read them on the iPad with an app. So yea, sync to dropbox....even if there isnt an app yet for the iPad you can simply go to the website and download w/e you want to view it.

Answer (score 0):

If you download IBooks 1.1 it can now sync PDF files with iTunes and display them without any issue. (I moved quite a few of my technical books over there!). Another method would be to use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) and synchronize the files between your desktop -> dropbox -> iPad. Keep in mind that files in Dropbox on the iPad can only be accessed and opened from within the Dropbox application. I know Dropbox can open PDF files as well.

Comment: I want to create my own app and store data in it. So this isn`t exactly what I wanted :)